# How Finagle aperture algorithm chooses "non overlapping" subsets?

Tags: scala, rest, subset, finagle, twitter-finagle

I have been reading about Finagle and trying to understand the code to figure out how Aperture's subset choice works.

I have seen that [ApertureLeastLoaded](https://github.com/twitter/finagle/blob/2c3bdc832c9fdb637dd6ed9d49db904c554b5165/finagle-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finagle/loadbalancer/aperture/ApertureLeastLoaded.scala) has a "useDeterministicOrdering" and an "EndpointFactory" which I guess should be the key points to make the decision of which clients to take in the subset.

While reading the "deterministic subsetting" section of [Google SRE's book](https://landing.google.com/sre/book/chapters/load-balancing-datacenter.html), I understood that the best way to pick a subset of servers from the client point of view, is to know the total number of clients, and a unique sequential identifier of the current client, that can be used as seed of the subset generator.

In Finagle I can't understand how this process is done (I'm not super familiar with Scala) and the documentation both on the website and in the code, explain just how the aperture paradigm works, but not very clear how the initial subset is chosen

I hope somebody can enlighten me

Answer (score 1):

One of the unique properties of Aperture is that its window is sized dynamically based on a clients offered load. That is, clients have a built in controller which can expand or shrink their window at runtime. This property is important as it allows clients to operate more efficiently and better adapt to a changing environment, but it does make it more complex to achieve a uniform load distribution across servers.

To contrast, the subsetting algorithm, as proposed by the Google SRE book, suggests that operators choose a static subset size which allows a uniform load distribution to be calculated analytically but introduces another static configuration that needs to be revisited as a system evolves.

Deterministic Aperture is, to the best of our knowledge, a novel algorithm for achieving a uniform load distribution while maintaining the dynamic properties of the window sizing mentioned above. From a high level, clients construct a topology of their peer cluster (which gives them a sense of ordering and proximity) and then derive a unique per-client permutation of the servers from the topology such that each server is uniformly represented across the permutations.

We are still in the early stages of testing this in production at Twitter, but early results look very promising. After we gather more empirical results, we hope to publish some more detailed content on how the algorithm works and its properties.

Comment: Thank you Ruben, could you please explain me better how " and then derive a unique per-client permutation of the servers from the topology such that each server is uniformly represented across the permutations." is achieved? 
You correctly said that Google SRE adds another static configuration, instead Aperture might be able to achieve the same result dynamically without knowing the other clients (just the servers out there), it would be interesting understanding how exactly this is done.